# Subscribe and Catch child control click event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click, controls

I have a form that contains a custom list control. In this list control, is a flexlayout control called **flpListBox** with rows of results.

I am having problems catching the click event of each item. I can MessageBox the sender object key (the song name in this case), and that is correct per row clicked, but I want to show the clicked result song name on the parent main form label **lblNowPlaying.Text**

In ListControl, I have this

```
public void Add(string Song, string Artist, string Album)
{
    var c = new ListControlItem();
    c.Name = "item" + (flpListBox.Controls.Count + 1);
    c.Margin = new Padding(0);
    c.Song = Song;
    c.Artist = Artist;
    c.Album = Album;
    c.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
    c.Click += ItemClicked;
    flpListBox.Controls.Add(c);
    SetupAnchors();
}

public event ItemClickEventHandler ItemClick;
public delegate void ItemClickEventHandler(object sender, int Index);

private void ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListControlItem c = (ListControlItem)sender;
   //MessageBox.Show(c.Song);

   ItemClick?.Invoke(this, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey(c.Song));
   //ItemClick?.Invoke(this, flpListBox.Controls.IndexOfKey((sender as ListControlItem).Song));
}
```

And in parent form Form1 I have

```
InitializeComponent();
ListControl1.ItemClick += new ListControl.ItemClickEventHandler(ListControl1_ItemClick);
```

```
private void ListControl1_ItemClick(object sender, int Index)
{
   MessageBox.Show("event caught");
   lblNowPlaying.Text = "Now Playing: item index " + Index;
}
```

The reference for ListControl1.ItemClick correctly refers back, so I don't understand why I can not catch the Song name from the child control, and send to parent form label.

[image: References are correct]

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned the wrong control name, after realizing that and making the correct changes the code worked as expected.